# Strange error with KeyPath on optional value

Tags: swift, xcode11, keypaths

Consider the following snippet of code

```swift
class A {
    
    var value: Int?
    
}

let a: A? = A()
let kp = \A.value
a?[keyPath: kp] = 10
print(a?.value)
```

This works perfectly and `Optional(10)` is printed as expected. In my actual app the field I'm trying to set this way is declared as `Date?` and it causes some strange errors. The MWE of my actual app is this:

```swift
class A {
    
    var value: Date?
    
}

let a: A! = A()
let kp = \A.value
a?[keyPath: kp] = Date() // Line with error
print(a?.value)
```

However the compiler complains about the highlighted line and says:

> Value of optional type 'Date?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Date'
>
> Fix: Coalesce using '??' to provide a default when the optional value contains 'nil'
>
> Fix: Force-unwrap using '!' to abort execution if the optional value contains 'nil'

Is this a bug of the compiler we can expect to be fixed before the final release or there's something I'm not understanding about key-paths?

I'm using Xcode 11 beta 3 but I've encountered the same problem also in beta 2. If it can be useful the actual code is [here](https://github.com/piscoTech/Workout/blob/master/Workout/Controller/FilterListTVC.swift#L216).

Comment: This is a bug, filed a report: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-11184

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing this without ! and ? works

```
let a = A()
let kp = \A.value
a[keyPath: kp] = Date() 
print(a.value)
```

or only as optional

```
let a: A? = A()
let kp = \A.value
a?[keyPath: kp] = Date() 
print(a?.value)
```

Comment: Strange stuff. Since with a normal optional it works I guess it's a bug of the compiler

Comment: @Joakim What's the reason it doesn't work with forced optional?

Comment: @PGDev, I can't really explain that since I don't fully understand how keypaths work with optionals in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into similar problem:

```swift
import Foundation

struct Outer {
    var inner: Inner

    init() {
        inner = Inner()
    }
}

struct Inner {
    var date: Date?
}

var outer = Outer()
outer[keyPath: \Outer.inner][keyPath: \Inner.date] = Date() // Line with error
print(outer.inner.date)
```

```
error: value of optional type 'Date?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Date'
outer[keyPath: \Outer.inner][keyPath: \Inner.date] = Date() // Line with error
                            ^
note: coalesce using '??' to provide a default when the optional value contains 'nil'
outer[keyPath: \Outer.inner][keyPath: \Inner.date] = Date() // Line with error
                            ^
                                                   ?? <#default value#>
note: force-unwrap using '!' to abort execution if the optional value contains 'nil'
outer[keyPath: \Outer.inner][keyPath: \Inner.date] = Date() // Line with error
                            ^
                                                  !
```

Strangely, casting the value to an optional works

```swift
outer[keyPath: \Outer.inner][keyPath: \Inner.date] = Date() as Date? // Works
```

Therefore, I believe a more general workaround to this problem is to explicitly cast the value to an optional `as Date?`